# Copy Past is not working in CKEDITOR

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to copy content form outlook and past in my CKEDITOR it not remaining same only under line and bold is present but color is not display please provide some suggestion

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Content pasted from Word or Outlook is unlikely to remain exactly the same - there are too many features in those programs which aren't supported in CKeditor.

However, to keep the font colours, families and sizes, you need to set [the `pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles` configuration option](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles) to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Now my text font color bg color are remaining same